# Apply json response to different divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, kohana

I have a login form that I am submitting using jQuery and ajaxForm plugin. The form is submitting fine and I am receiving the JSON response aok:

```
{"username":"Enter your username","password":"password must not be empty"}
```

My form is as follows using kohana framework:

```
<?php echo form::open('login',array('id'=>'login'));?>
<div id="username_errors"></div>        
<?php   echo form::label('username','Username');?><br/> 
<?php   echo form::input('username','',array('id' => 'username','class'=>'login          text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'));?><br/>
<div id="password_errors"></div>        
<?php   echo form::label('password','Password');?><br/>
<?php   echo form::password('password','',array('id' => 'password','class'=>'text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'));?><br/>

<?php   echo form::label('remember_me','Remember Me');
    echo form::checkbox('Remember Me', 'remember_me', FALSE);?><br/>

<?php   echo form::submit('submit','Login');
    echo form::close();?>
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery('.form #login').ajaxForm({ 
    data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
    dataType:'json',
    url:'login',
    success: function(data){
        if (data.redirect == 'home') {
        window.location.href=data.redirect;
        }//else append error messages to relevant divs

        }
        });
```

I want to take my error messages(if there are any) and populate the relevent divs with the error messages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close, try:

```
jQuery('.form #login').ajaxForm({ 
    data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
    dataType:'json',
    url:'login',
    success: function(data){
        if (data.redirect == 'home') {
            window.location.href=data.redirect;
        } else {
            $('#username_errors').html(data.username);    
            $('#password_errors').html(data.password);        
        }
    });
```

Comment: Lovely. I think I had a block. I think I was looking for something complicated. Cheers.